# Calculating how many of a specific number is in a csv file

Tags: c#, csv

I have a csv file that has 100,000 IQ Values in it. The IQ's range from 34-165, so obviously there are going to be a lot of numbers that are the same. I am trying to write code that will tell me how many of the numbers are the same. For example: there is 11 people with an IQ of 49 and 120 people with an IQ of 62. I figured it would be easiest to use a List, but I'm a beginner and still learning. So was just wondering what block of code would be able to calculate that?

Comment: What is the structure of your csv file ?

Comment: Easiest way to do stuff like this is to install/use R.  It's a couple of lines in R.  Or do you have a specific language you must use?

Comment: This could be some nice onliner in bash, using `cut`/`sed`, `sort` and `uniq -c` ;)

Comment: Sorry should of specified, I am using C#... Sorry if this is a dumb question, but what do you mean by the structure of my csv file?

Comment: Is your CSV just the numbers (e.g. 34,62,143...), or is there identifying info with the numbers (e.g Doe,John,56...)?

Comment: They are just numbers separated by commas.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem breaks neatly into two pieces: reading in a csv, and processing the results.

It would be easier for the good people of Stack Overflow to help if you provided a little more information about the csv, or an example of the code you have tried thus far, but we can still make an attempt with what we have.

For reading in the csv, start here:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

If your csv is a list of numbers separated by commas (120, 62, 37...) this is a very simple operation.  If it has more information (if, for example, each line is "name, age, gender, IQ, country of birth...") it will require a little more work, but is still very easily doable.

I'll start with the assumption that your file is a simple list of numbers, separated by commas.

so:

```
import csv
with open('yourfile.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader: 
        # there is only one row!
        # it is a list of numbers (as string values)
        # ie, ['34','35','120','91'...]
        for x in xrange(34,166):  
            # x starts at 34, and iterates to 166-1 = 165
            print x, row.count(str(x)) 
            # 'str(x)' converts the int to a string
            # 'count' counts the number of times that string is present in the list 'row'
```

You could also add the values to a dictionary for later use: instead of the print statement, define a dict - "iqs = {}" and:

```
iqs[x] = row.count(str(x))
```

Now you can recover your values at will:

```
iqs[120]
10 #output
```

putting it together (with comments removed):

```
import csv
with open('yourfile.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    iqs= {}
    for row in reader: 
        for x in xrange(34,166):  
            iqs[x] = row.count(str(x))
```

If you csv is more complicated, you can do two loops, the first parsing the csv (ie, creating a your list instead of 'row') and the second iterating from 34 to 165:

```
import csv
with open('yourfile.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    lst= []
    for row in reader: 
        #parse row
        lst.append(iq_value_from this row)
    iqs= {}
    for x in xrange(34,166):  
        iqs[x] = lst.count(str(x))
```

finally, if you desire to graph the results, it may be more useful to create two lists, and plot them with the matplotlib package (http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html)

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
with open('yourfile.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    lst = []
    x_values= []
    y_values=[]
    for row in reader: 
        #parse row
        lst.append(iq_value_from this row)
    iqs= {}
    for x in xrange(34,166):  
        x_values.append(x)
        y_values.append(lst.count(str(x)))

plt.plot(x_values,y_values)
plt.show()
```

Comment: for some reason I though you said you were using python, when in fact you had no language specified.... oh well.  here's a python solution....

Comment: Sorry, I ended up specifying later in the comments. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

As for wich type of collection to use, I suggest using a Generic Dictionary using the IQ value as the key and the sum as the value. Read your CSV and increment the value for each IQ.

You can either prefill your Dictionary with every valid IQ value or add entries on the run, checking if a Dictionary entry exists for a given IQ and then adding or incrementing it.

For larger Problems or when facing performance issues you can use an Array of int32 with enough elements to keep all valid IQ values, calculating the index maybe as:

```
int[] Sums = new int[100];
// Loop this over your CSV
int IQ = 120;
Sums[IQ - 50]++;
```